# What is the name of this thing shown in "Call Me By Your Name" movie?

Tags: image-identification

[image: Still with samovar highlighted]

What is the name of this thing shown in "Call Me By Your Name" movie? It looks like an antique object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a [samovar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samovar), a device used to heat water. [Here](http://yesofcorsa.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/Samovar-Wallpaper-For-Mobile.jpg) is a similar example. Fancier ones can be seen in the slideshow at [this BBC/NPR article](http://wnpr.org/post/tea-tuesdays-cold-weather-gogol-and-rise-russian-samovar).